# How can I use conditional statement in Python + MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

For example,
I can update the data like this:

```
sql= "UPDATE USER SET PASSWORD='+pwd+' WHERE NAME='+name+'"
```

But now I have some data in SQL database, and I want to do this:
In table A, column a, row 1 to n
If I found a data of which the length is larger than 15,
I will set `column b = column a`, and `column b = ''`

But I think this statement will not work:

```
sql = "UPDATE A SET b=a where len(a)>15"
```

So how can I do this kind of thing?

BTW, if the condition is "the first symbol of data is Chinese symbol"?
How can I use a `IsChinese(str)` function to update my data?

[image]

Comment: cursor.execute( "update cn_punishments-org set Company = '' where " + isChinese(Company[0]) )

Comment: Thank you for your response, I think you are right although haven't try yet.

Comment: I am sorry that this statement doesn't work, I think the variable Company doesn't exist in python .

Comment: Mine is just a hint for you. If the variable doesn't exist, how did you think you can use it? Form it before calling the execute function and use.

Comment: I think when I use an sql update statement, it is a kind of ergodic for data, but for python the variable Company can only form outside this function? so when I change my cursor to another place,  I can't use 'for' or other python function to update the variable Company..

Answer (score 0):

you can also try like this in python :

```
obj = table_name.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)
if IsChinese(obj.company[0]):
      obj.company = ''
obj.save()
```

for more you can refer here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create